# Issue with Like Query in MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

Following problem:

If I want to search with 'Last Name' it works but if it is a variable in this form `$results['22']['BuyerName2']`

Here is what I got so far:

```
$rr=$results[22]['BuyerName2'];
echo $rr; //echos Last Name

$stmt = $db->prepare("Update base_1 SET UpdateStatus=2 WHERE BuyerName LIKE ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%$rr%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

If I put instead `$rr` the Name directly in the bind value part it works. But not with `$rr`.

Comment: Are you sure you're using double quotes, not single quotes?

Comment: And when you say it doesn't work, what happens exactly? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error? Or does it just not update anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there are extra spaces in `$rr`. Try:

```
$rr = trim($results[22]['BuyerName2']);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%$rr%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I am unsure whether the $ becomes escaped or not in the string you binded. As far as I know, only the underscore and the percent sign stay unescaped. I would suggest to try:

```
$rr = "%".$rr."%";
```

and edit the line to:

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, $rr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```